# C# generated PDF files doesn't open in PDF readers. Error shows damaged or corrupt file

Tags: c#, pdf, binary-data

I am trying to save imageData as pdf file on server directory. Html5Canvas imageData was sent to server and after conversion in bytes array, tried to save as PDF file. File generated successfully on specified path but the generated file doesn't open correctly in most of the PDF readers(i.e. Adobe Reader, Foxit reader etc) and show error that file is either damaged or corrupt but it open correctly in MS Edge browser. I want them to show in common PDF reader too. Can you please suggest the solution. Here is my server side code.

```
public static string SaveImage(string imageData, string userEmail, int quantity)
    {
        string completePath = @"~\user-images\";
        string imageName = "sample_file2.pdf";
        string fileNameWitPath = completePath + imageName;
        byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imageData);
        File.WriteAllBytes(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(fileNameWitPath), bytes);
    }
```

Same output generated for this code

```
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(fileNameWitPath), FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        fs.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        fs.Close();
```

and for this too.

```
 using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(fileNameWitPath), FileMode.Create))
        {

            using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fs))
            {

                byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(imageData);

                bw.Write(data);

                bw.Close();
            }

        }
```

Comment: So you're creating a PDF on the browser? Since you're not doing any conversions here

Answer (score 1):

If you just save a raster image format file (like PNG or JPG one) with a `.PDF` file extension it doesn't make it a PDF file; it still remains an image file just with another extension. So it probably works in some browsers because they may do file format detection that is not based on extension alone.

To generate an actual PDF file you will need to employ some conversion. Consider one of the following libraries for this:

- iTextSharp: https://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/ (AGPL = a free software license that allows non-commercial use. For commercial use you need to purchase a commercial license)
- PDFSharp http://www.pdfsharp.net/ (free, MIT license)
- ABCpdf.NET http://www.websupergoo.com/products.htm#abcpdf (proprietary)

Comment: iText and iTextSharp are released as free / open source software. Free / open source software is *licensed*. In the case of iText(Sharp), the license is AGPL. The AGPL allows you to use the software for free as long as you distribute your own software under the same license. This is similar to the license that is in place when you use code found on Stack Overflow: https://www.eurostaffgroup.com/media-hub/how-can-i-use-code-snippets-found-on-stack-overflow-65809/

Comment: @BrunoLowagie thanks for edit. Indeed it is important to check what `free` means in a particular case before using something. I also added info that `PDFSharp` is licensed under much less strict `MIT License`.

Comment: Indeed: I've given a lot of talks about licensing, and in my experience, developers aren't always aware of the implications of using free / open source software. See for instance: [an introduction to IP and Legal](http://www.slideshare.net/blowagie/open-source-an-introduction-to-ip-and-legal) and [How can large open source projects be monetized?](http://www.slideshare.net/blowagie/how-can-large-open-source-projects-be-monetized)

Comment: Thanks @AndrewSklyarevsky, your suggested solution works. Thanks once again.